# Access based on Column value in Apache Sentry

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-sentry

I know we have Column level access in Apache Sentry. But is it possible to provide Access based on Column value also rather than just column ? Or Is creating a View the better and only option here ?

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to provide Access based on the column values rather than just column.

You can restrict the access only upto column level i.e., based on column name and not based on the values present in the table data for the column.

Creating a view is a better option.